# Work related words

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

The main thing I want to know is how to distinguish days off from sick days. Many jobs have two separate categories. *Malsantagoj* doesn't seem right and I thought of *libertagoj* but technically a sick day is a day off too. Maybe *libertago por malsano*?

> *Mi ne iros al la laborejo morgaŭ, sed ĉio estas en ordo, ĉar mi havas sufiĉajn libertagojn por malsano.*

In addition to that what about overtime? I found *pluslaboro* in the dictionary but I also thought of *kromaj horoj* which made a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that these are international concepts? I've seen it broken down in even finer detail: vacation, national holidays, personal choice holidays, and sick time - all of this referred to collectively as "paid time off." There were internal rules about each one was to be handled, but I was never confident that these rules were the same from company to company let alone from culture to culture.

What is it specifically you're trying to say and in what context. Here's an off the cuff example.

- I have used up my sick time and will have to use vacation.
- Mi elĉerpis mian forpermeson pro malsano kaj mi devos uzi feri-horojn.

I suspect that "overtime" (especially in the sense "more than 40 hours) is an American concept - but *pluslaboro* does seem to be a calque of German "Mehrarbeit" which is similar. (Not sure how that relates to "Überstunden".)

Another option is *kromlaboro* which is what Google Translate gives and is found in Tatoeba. Your suggestion of *kromaj horoj* looks similar to the French expression "Heures supplémentaires"

Comment: To me kromlaboro sounded like a side job, like an extra job, not working more hours, which is why I picked kromaj horoj. If people use kromlaboro or pluslaboro that's fine, I'll use it, I've just never had to talk about these things and just because it's in the dictionary doesn't mean it's what people say. I didn't really have an examples of how I wanted to use the terms but I didn't really think about whether other countries have sick days and just days off for any reason.

Comment: I hear you. Personally, I wasn't familiar with any of these terms - and as I mentioned in my answer, I'm not fully convinced they'll be understood as intended depending on your audience.

Comment: I forgot to check my other dictionaries and I found ekstraj horoj and kromlaboro, I couldn't find anything else for vacation days vs. sick days. You're right though that there aren't always short precise translations of terms like this. A couple extra words for clarification never hurt anybody. :p Thanks for you help.

Comment: I thought I heard somewhere that "libertempo" referred to vacation from work. It had to do with someone explaining the difference between "libera tempo" and "libertempo" where "libera tempo" would be the "free time" in which you would read or do some other hobby and "libertempo" would refer to time away from work.

Comment: @ChrisMcDowell - That makes sense to me but doesn't clarify how to distinguish different kinds of time away from work. Is sick time included in libertempo? Are optional holidays included? I suspect different people would see this differently.